# Configurar host virtual en NGINX para que resuelva el dominio con y sin www

Tags: nginx

Estoy configurando el vhost de NGINX para un sitio nuevo que funciona con wordpress.

Su URL pongamos que es "www.ejemplo1.com". Cuando accedo con www, NGINX me lo redirecciona a "ejemplo1.com" para no tener contenido duplicado en "ejemplo1.com" y "www.ejemplo1.com".

He instalado el plugin de yoast seo hace un par de dias y veo que google me ha indexado con "www" y sin las "www".

Para evitar contenido duplicado, ¿retiro las URLs del google search console que tengan el subdominio "www"?

```
    server {

    server_name ejemplo1.com;

    root /var/www/html/ejemplo1/www;
    index index.php;

    location / {
        try_files $uri [MENTION=532983]Apache[/MENTION];
        # rewrite ^/([^\.]+)$ /index.php/$1 break;
    }

    location ~ ^/\.user\.ini {
        deny all;
    }

    location ~*  \.(svg|svgz)$ {
        types {}
        default_type image/svg+xml;
    }

    location = /favicon.ico {
        log_not_found off;
        access_log off;
    }

    location = /robots.txt {
        allow all;
        log_not_found off;
        access_log off;
    }

    location [MENTION=532983]Apache[/MENTION] {
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP  $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_pass [url]http://127.0.0.1:8080;[/url]
    }

    location ~[^?]*/$ {
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP  $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_pass [url]http://127.0.0.1:8080;[/url]
    }

    location ~ \.php$ {
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP  $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_pass [url]http://127.0.0.1:8080;[/url]
    }


    location ~/\. {
        deny all;
        access_log off;
        log_not_found off;
    }



    listen 443 ssl; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/ejemplo1.com/fullchain.pem; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/ejemplo1.com/privkey.pem; # managed by Certbot
    include /etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-nginx.conf; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_dhparam /etc/letsencrypt/ssl-dhparams.pem; # managed by Certbot

}
 server {
    if ($host = ejemplo1.com) {
        return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
    } # managed by Certbot


    server_name ejemplo1.com;
    listen 80;
    return 404; # managed by Certbot

}
```

Comment: ¿Qué URL tienes configurada en wordpress como canónima? ¿Con www o sin www? ¿Cómo tienes configurado el subdominio `www.ejemplo1.com` en NGINX? Es importante saber si has usado un 301 (redirección permanente) u otro tipo de configuración. Por favor, comparte el bloque `server` de dicho subdominio.

Comment: En wordpress sin www, en nginx server_name ejemplo1.com;

Comment: Ok, URL canónica correcta. Pero falta responder a la parte más importante de mi pregunta: ¿y la configuración del subdominio `www.ejemplo1.com` en NGINX? Vuelvo a insistir que es importante saber si has usado un 301 u otro tipo de configuración basada en redirecciones. Por favor, comparte el bloque `server` de dicho subdominio para poder adaptarlo a tus necesidades. Si no tienes ese bloque y es lo que deseas hacer desde cero, indícalo igualmente.